# Adding aliases with string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, alias

Can I add alias from a query with a string concatenated on it?

Example:

```
SELECT u.name, u.age, u.status + ' (example)' as user_status // pseudo code
FROM user u
```

Expected result:

```
user1: Ben, 21, single (example)
user2: Alex, 22, single (example)
```

I have tried `u.status + ' (example)'` but its giving me `0` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT u.name, u.age, CONCAT(u.status, ' (example)') as user_status 
FROM user u
```

With strings, you don't add (that's a numeric action), you concatenate :)

Read more about MySQL String functions, there are plenty of useful ones here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I just found out the answer by trial and error but you gave the answer first so +1 to you! CONCAT(u.status, ' (example)')

Comment: @HardSpocker - great :) Tip - if you also accept the answer other people will not come here to try and help, because they will see this is resolved..